# Column reference 'updated_at' is ambiguous in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to upsert a post:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS upsert_post;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_post(
    title text,
    content text,
    short_id text DEFAULT NULL,
    image text DEFAULT NULL,
    status post_status DEFAULT 'draft',
    updated_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
    published_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS SETOF posts
AS $$
DECLARE
    post_id uuid;
BEGIN
    -- Get the id based on the provided short_id
    SELECT id INTO post_id FROM posts as p 
    WHERE p.short_id = upsert_post.short_id;

    -- Upsert the post and return the changed row
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO posts as i (
        id,
        status,
        title,
        content,
        image,
        updated_at,
        published_at,
        created_at
    )
    VALUES (
        COALESCE(post_id, uuid_generate_v4()),
        upsert_post.status,
        upsert_post.title, 
        upsert_post.content,
        upsert_post.image,
        COALESCE(upsert_post.updated_at, now()),
        COALESCE(upsert_post.published_at, now()),
        COALESCE(upsert_post.created_at, now())
    )
    ON CONFLICT (id, updated_at) DO UPDATE
    SET
        title = EXCLUDED.title,
        content = EXCLUDED.content,
        image = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.image, i.image),
        updated_at = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.updated_at, i.updated_at),
        published_at = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.published_at, i.published_at),
        created_at = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.created_at, i.created_at)
    RETURNING *;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get the error:

```json
{
  code: '42702',
  details: 'It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.',
  hint: null,
  message: 'column reference "updated_at" is ambiguous'
}
```

I have used aliases everywhere I know possible. How can I get this working without renaming my `upsert_post` parameters with a prefix `i_` or something similar?

Comment: never name parameters the same as column names

Comment: @nbk - Thanks for downvoting this without giving any explanation, examples, or perceived standard of practice.  Sure it can be more difficult, but there are aliases for this reasons, otherwise postgres would not allow it.

Comment: Read [Variable substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST). Bottom line you have a conflict between `updated_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,` and `INSERT INTO posts as i ( ... updated_at, ...`.

Comment: Actually, that is not the problem.  It works fine with `INSERT INTO` if I get rid of the `DO UPDATE`. the problem is the parameter `updated_at` in conflict with the on conflict `updated_at`. But I already knew that, just not how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was the input parameter conflicting with the `ON CONFLICT` parameter.

There are three real answers I finally found.

### 1. #variable_conflict

Postgres has three variables to use for this use case:

```sql
#variable_conflict error
#variable_conflict use_variable
#variable_conflict use_column
```

But I got it working thanks to the [Variable Substitution Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST) provided above:

```sql
RETURNS SETOF posts
AS $$
#variable_conflict use_column
DECLARE
    post_id uuid;
BEGIN
```

### 2. ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT

The problem with my code above was the `ON CONFLICT` not allowing you to use aliases with it. If you know a way, please let me know. Otherwise, I simply just used the name of the compound constraint with `ON CONSTRAINT` instead.

```sql
 ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT posts_pkey DO UPDATE
```

**Edit**: You could also name the constraint anything you want, in the schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (
  ...
  CONSTRAINT id_updated_at_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, updated_at)
  ...
);
```

### 3. Create a sub function

Basically you could just create a function `_upsert_post()` which does take prefixed parameters. Then just pass your non prefixed parameters into this function:

**upsert_post**

```sql
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM _upsert_post(id, status, title...);
```

To say that you have to use `prefixes` is simply not true. In my case, the user would have to change the frontend code to use different parameters than the backend code. This can be important for teams.

Comment: It is not that the `DO UPDATE` does not allow alias it is that it does not allow <table_name/alias>.<field_name>. Per [INSERT]: *When referencing a column with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE, do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column. For example, INSERT INTO table_name ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET table_name.col = 1 is invalid (this follows the general behavior for UPDATE).*.

Comment: Right, but I wasn't doing that, it was inside the `ON CONFLICT (id, updated_at)` that was the problem, not the `DO UPDATE SET`. I can't do `ON CONFLICT (i.id, i.updated_at)...`, that was where the conflict happened, unless you know away around that.

Comment: The `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` was where I was going to go. You didn't need to name the constraint explicitly, a `\d posts` in `psql` would have show you the name generated by Postgres. It would most likely would have been `posts_pkey`.

Comment: Thanks, that is simpler and makes sense.

Comment: (Tips for posting: try to avoid commentary on meta-issues like voting or how a question is received, and refrain from adding signatures. All this stuff tends to be removed by curators for reasons of brevity and clarity anyway, so it saves volunteers from some bother if it is not added in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

i needed to adept the function, as user typ and function are supplied and create table would also help much

In short you should never name your variables like column names, so that postgres has no more problem differentiate them

the idea behind short_id i can only guess. but i think you should also enter it, when inserting a new row

```
CREATE TABLe posts (id text PRIMARY KEY,    
    status text DEFAULT 'draft',
  title text,
  content text,
    short_id text DEFAULT NULL,
    image text DEFAULT NULL,
    
    updated_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
    published_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE (id, updated_at)
)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_post(
    f_title text,
    f_content text,
    f_short_id text DEFAULT NULL,
    f_image text DEFAULT NULL,
    f_status text DEFAULT 'draft',
    f_updated_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
    f_published_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL,
    f_created_at timestamptz DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS SETOF posts
AS $$
DECLARE
    post_id uuid;
BEGIN
    -- Get the id based on the provided short_id
    SELECT id INTO post_id FROM posts as p 
    WHERE p.short_id = f_short_id;

    -- Upsert the post and return the changed row
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO posts as i (
        id,
        status,
        title,
        content,
        image,
        updated_at,
        published_at,
        created_at
    )
    VALUES (
        COALESCE(post_id, gen_random_uuid ()),
        f_status,
        f_title, 
        f_content,
        f_image,
        COALESCE(f_updated_at, now()),
        COALESCE(f_published_at, now()),
        COALESCE(f_created_at, now())
    )
    ON CONFLICT (id, updated_at) DO UPDATE
    SET
        title = EXCLUDED.title,
        content = EXCLUDED.content,
        image = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.image, i.image),
        updated_at = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.updated_at, i.updated_at),
        published_at = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.published_at, i.published_at),
        created_at = COALESCE(EXCLUDED.created_at, i.created_at)
    RETURNING *;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION
> ```

```
SELECT
    routine_name
FROM 
    information_schema.routines
WHERE 
    routine_type = 'FUNCTION'
AND
    routine_schema = 'public';
```

| routine_name |
| --- |
| upsert_post |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
SELECT upsert_post('A'::TEXT,'b'::TEXT,'C'::TEXT,'D'::TEXT,'draft'::TEXT,NOW(),NOW(), NOW())
```

| upsert_post |
| --- |
| (f9bb1bd4-62f7-4380-b088-5185db0fca40,draft,A,b,,D,"2023-06-25 18:50:17.61884+01","2023-06-25 18:50:17.61884+01","2023-06-25 18:50:17.61884+01") |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM posts
```

| id | status | title | content | short_id | image | updated_at | published_at | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f9bb1bd4-62f7-4380-b088-5185db0fca40 | draft | A | b | *null* | D | 2023-06-25 18:50:17.61884+01 | 2023-06-25 18:50:17.61884+01 | 2023-06-25 18:50:17.61884+01 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EyAMh2Tz)

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time, but I specifically said I didn't want to use prefixes in the input parameters.

Comment: you can't as i told you already, postgres can not determine between both and takes always the database column so that short_id = short_id is always true, as you see my way works perfectly fine,  and it is good practise to use f_ or p_ for Variables so that you know where the variable comes from